# Can't filter observable collection, but accessible in my code C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, lambda

I'm trying to filter out objects in my observable collection..

```
var checkedRows = Servers.Where(s => s.NodeName != null).ToList(); //there, you now have a list of checked rows
```

When I debug, this comes back as null. However, I have a test block that runs the following (in the same function)

```
foreach(Server obj in Servers)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Server: {obj.NodeName}\nChecked:{obj.isChecked.ToString()}");
}
```

And the above code prints the information without any issues.

Here is the server declaration

```
public ObservableCollection<Server> Servers { get; set; }
```

Comment: That should not give you `null` even if nothing matches the `Where`. I think there is something else you are not showing.

Comment: Where() and ToList() will never return null. What does "this comes back as null" refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Your **NodeName** could be `null`, could be `String.Empty`, so It is a good idea to check both with `IsNullOrEmpty(string)`.

Try with:

```
var checkedRows = Servers.Where(s => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.NodeName)));
```

Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx).